# Splitting a string into consonant-vowel sequences

Tags: regex, python-3.x, split, tokenize

I am trying to split a string as follows:

1. Zero or more consonants followed by zero or more vowels are a taken as a token.
2. All other characters are taken as a token.

For example, `'yes, oat is good'` is split as `['ye', 's', ',', ' ', 'oa', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'goo', 'd']`.

Trying regex `re.compile(r'[bcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz]*[aeiou]*').findall('yes, oat is good')` gives me `['yes', '', '', 'oa', 't', '', 'i', 's', '', 'goo', 'd', '']`. Why is `'yes'` not split into `'ye'` and `'s'`?

Then, trying `re.compile(r'[bcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz]*[aeiou]*|.').findall('yes, oat is good')` gives me the same result. Why does it not capture `','` and `' '`?

Finally, is there a way to avoid getting empty strings?

Comment: your regex is correct, just remove the vowels 'e' and 'u' in [bcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz]

Answer (score 2):

You should not include the letter `e` as one of the consonants. Aside from that, you should use an alternation pattern to match all the other characters as a token. Also use a positive lookahead pattern to ensure the pattern that matches zero or more consonants followed by zero or more vowels matches at least one alphabet:

```
re.findall(r'[^a-z]|(?=[a-z])[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*[aeiou]*', 'yes, oat is good', re.I)
```

This returns:

```
['ye', 's', ',', ' ', 'oa', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'goo', 'd']
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. But my second question is left unanswered. Why does the regex I used miss `','` and `' '`?